# React. Mousewheel.deltaY reacts to if statement, but not to switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

React component listens  for wheel scroll:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.holder.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.handleScroll);
  }
```

And reacts to it:

```
  handleScroll(e) {
    switch (e) {
      case e.deltaY > 0:
        console.log('positive');
      default:
        console.log('negative');
    }

    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      console.log('positive');
    } else {
      console.log('negative');
    }
  }
```

It works fine with if/else statement, but doesn't works with switch, can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with React. Switch statements don't work like that. You are comparing the result of `e.deltaY > 0` to `e`, which will never match. `e.deltaY > 0` will always be `true` or `false`. `e` is an event object and will never be`true` or `false`. You can do something like this instead...

```
switch (e.deltaY > 0) {
  case true:
    console.log('positive');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('negative');
}
```

I recommend using a simple `if` statement though since your only cases are `true` and `false`

Comment: Thank you for explanation, Charlie.

Answer (score 1):

From Doc [`Switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

> switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then **looks for the** **first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using strict comparison, ===)** and transfers control to it.

```
typeof e === typeof (e.deltaY > 0 ) //sometime true and sometime false

e ===  (e.deltaY > 0 ) //sometime true and sometime false
```

Everytime `===` will give different result and you will not get expected result